# Regex in cucumber step definition breaks syntax highlighting in Notepad++

Tags: ruby, cucumber, notepad++

Imagine this simple auto generated step definition:

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"$/ do |s|
```

Now, I use Notepad++ for my Cucumber tests. Everything after the regex part ending with `"` will be marked as a **string** in Notepad++ until we run into the same character again.

I could replace `"([^"]*)"` with `'([^"]*)'` to avoid it from happening.

Is this considered to be a good idea or is there a more suitable solution out there?

Answer (score 5):

You can't replace `"([^"]*)"` with `'([^"]*)'`, because regexp will change the meaning, but you can take this regexp in brackets:

```
Then(/^I should see "([^"]*)"$/) do |s|
end
```